# using radio button in windows phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, radio-button

I am making use of about 14 radio buttons using a pivot control page, with two options in each set of radio button I have to select one as the right option, then at the back there are some specific integers which are assigned with each radio button and are to be used at last, please help in this context. 
The following method doesn't work for me:

```
if (radioButton3.IsChecked == true)
{
    b = 2;
}
else
{
   b = 0;
}
```

Comment: at the last i need to add up the numbers which are set behind the radiobutton check option. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your var b a local variable?

if you want to keep these value , you'd better ensure its variable scope.